# initFoodModel is not a function Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findAll')

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

---

wishList.js

```
const { initFoodModel } = require("../../model/FoodModel");
const { initWishlistModel } = require("../../model/wishListModel");
const initWishlistModel = async () =\> {
try {
const sequelize = await getConnection();
const Food = await initFoodModel()
const User = await initUserModel()
const Wishlist = sequelize.define("Wishlist", wishlistModel, {
freezeTableName: true,
});

        Wishlist.belongsTo(Food, { foreignKey: 'Food_id', targetKey: 'Food_id' });
        Wishlist.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
        await Wishlist.sync({ alter: true });
        return Wishlist;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }

};

module.exports = { initWishlistModel };
```

listFood.js

```
const  {initWishlistModel}  = require("../../model/wishListModel");
const { initFoodModel } = require("../../model/FoodModel");
const getFood = async (req, res) =\> {
try {
const { Food_id } = req.params
const user_id = req.token.user.id;
console.log(req.token.user.id);
const schema = await initFoodModel();

        const wishlist = await initWishlistModel();
    
        let isWishlisted = await wishlist.findAll({ where: { Food_id: Food_id, user_id: user_id } })
        console.log(isWishlisted);
    
        if (isWishlisted) {
            return send(res, RESPONSE.SUCCESS, "already wishlisted")
        }
        return send(res, RESPONSE.ERROR })
    
    
    
    // let check = await schema.findOne({ where: { Food_id: Food_id, stat: true }, });
    // if (check.length === 0) {

// return send(res, RESPONSE.ITM_NOT_FOUND);
 // }
 // return send(res, RESPONSE.SUCCESS, { check })

} catch (err) {
console.log(err.message);
return send(res, RESPONSE.ERROR, err.stack)
}
};
```

I want to check whether the given `food_id` is there in `wishlist` or not

I have already checked all the files, the `initFoodModel` is properly defined

this error occurs only when i try to use `initFoodModel` in `wishList`, if i use `initfoodModel` directly it works fine. [check commented lines]

Comment: What are you exporting from `/model/FoodModel`?

Answer (score 1):

i have been using unwanted circular requires, thats why i ended up with empty objects,I would suggest to remove all the unnecessary requires when you don't need the other models.